# How can i check if MySQL server is alive from C# MOBILE before i connect to my database

Tags: c#, mysql

I need a quick way to check if the server that runs MySQL is started from C# mobile.
I tried with Socket ... very slowly !!!
... and Ping class does not exist in C # mobile

```
IPHostEntry myHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry("192.168.2.222");
IPEndPoint host = new IPEndPoint(myHostEntry.AddressList[0], 3306);

Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
s.Connect(host);
if (s.Connected) { 
      MessageBox.Show("Ping Ok!!!"); 
} else {
       MessageBox.Show("Ping not Ok !!!");
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions ???

Answer (score 0):

If you can host some kind of script on the server, where MySQL is located then write a simple script that connects to local MySQL and prints 1 on success and 0 on failure. Query the script with HTTP from C# mobile. This would be most reliable solution imho.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your timeouts and remove the dns-resolve.

```
IPEndPoint host = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.2.222"), 3306);

Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
s.ReceiveTimeout = 100;
s.SendTimeout = 100;
SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
s.Connect(host);
if (s.Connected) { 
      MessageBox.Show("Ping Ok!!!"); 
} else {
       MessageBox.Show("Ping not Ok !!!");
}
```

But this can unreliable in a high latency environment (mobile-networks)

Comment: I need an alternative to the Ping class that is not available in C #  mobile.Socket is very slow ..
So I eliminate more possible errors:
Not connected to wifi network or the server is closed ...

Comment: [a custom implementation of ping](http://www.codeplanet.eu/tutorials/csharp/4-tcp-ip-socket-programmierung-in-csharp.html)

Answer (score 0):

The server might be alive and healthy, but your "health check" may timeout leading you to think it's dead; on the other hand, you may find out your server is perfectly healthy and you proceed with your queries, which in turn timeout (it's not that different a situation).

I'd suggest you assume the server is alive *AND* assume every query can and will timeout, handling appropriately the various conditions.

Comment: I believe he wouldn't be asking so if there was no good reason to check the server before. although you are absolutely right that an error can occur anywhen.

Comment: What I'm trying to point out here is that even if you "health check" the server before querying it, when it's time to actually run the query you might no longer be able to (timeout, network goes down, and so on). This holds true even in a non-mobile environment (what if the database/application/firewall/proxy/AD/etc. crashes ? what if switches blow up ? you get the picture ...). In short: assume queries WILL fail and adjust accordingly, it's easier and involves less checking.

Comment: Alex, I perfectly understand you and totally agree, but I simply guess that there is some rational reason behind the question. :-) Maybe server is offline from time to time and it has nothing to do with network errors... Maybe Ciprian has no access to the code that is going to be executed after checking if MySQL is alive (and wants to minimize the risk of failure)... Actually he never said he is going to execute any query afterwards. :-)